# Populating a list with user input

Tags: beginner, haskell, io

I am trying to learn me some Haskell because I found it to be an interesting language. Right now, I am trying to implement a function in Haskell to get acquainted with the language. The function just gets user input and adds the input numbers to a list of floats.

```
get_budget_values _values _index _length = do
    tmp_value <- getLine

    let new_value = read tmp_value :: Float
    let new_values = new_value : _values
    let new_index = _index + 1

    if new_index < _length
        then get_budget_values new_values new_index _length
        else return new_values
```

So, is this a proper way to implement a function like that in Haskell? What beginner mistakes am I making? Are there any standard ways of doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Add type signatures to top-level functions

You should always add a type signature to top-level functions:

```
get_budget_values :: [Float] -> Int -> Int -> IO [Float]
get_budget_values _values _index _length = do
    ...
```

## Make functions easy to use and hard to misuse

However, this function's type is weird. We want to get `_length` values, so why do we have to supply them first? That's error prone. Our funtion should have the type `Int -> IO [Float]` instead:

```
get_budget_values :: Int -> IO [Float]
get_budget_values n = go [] 0 n
  where
    go values index len = do
      tmp_value <- getLine

      let new_value = read tmp_value
      let new_values = new_value : values
      let new_index = index + 1

      if new_index < len
          then go new_values new_index len
          else return new_values
```

Note that due to `get_budget_values`' type signature we don't have to use `:: Float` at `read temp_value` anymore.

## Follow naming conventions and use existing library functions

Still, our function is sub-par, since we don't follow the common naming convention (`camelCase`) on the one hand don't  use library functions for our advantage.

So let's say we have `doNTimes :: Int -> IO a -> IO [a]` so that `doNTimes n action` repeats the `action` `n` times and collects the results in a list. Then we can write

```
getBudgetValues :: Int -> IO [Float]
getBudgetValues n = doNTimes n getSingleFloat
  where
    getSingleFloat = do
       tmpValue <- getLine
       return (read tmpValue)
```

The `getLine` followed by `read` approach is so common that there is a function for that, namely `readLn`:

```
    getSingleFloat = readLn
```

We end up with

```
getBudgetValues :: Int -> IO [Float]
getBudgetValues n = doNTimes n readLn
```

What's missing is `doNTimes`. Now, we know that there is `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`, which is almost correct, but we would end up with `[IO Float]` instead of `IO [Float]`. But there's also `sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]`.*

Therefore, we can write

```
doNTimes :: Int -> IO a -> IO [a]
doNTimes n action = sequence (replicate n action)
```

## The final result

This function is also often used and available as `replicateM` in `Control.Monad`. We end up with

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

getBudgetValues :: Int -> IO [Float]
getBudgetValues n = replicateM n readLn
```

## Exercises

Write `replicate` and `sequence` yourself without looking at their respective source code. `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` should fulfil the following properties for *positive* `n`:

```
let result = replicate n x
in length result == n && all (== x) result
```

For any non-positive `n`, the list should be empty.

`sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]` should execute the actions and collect their results, e.g.

```
sequence [putStrLn "Hello", putStrLn "World"]
```

should print `Hello` and `World` on two lines and return `[(),()]`.

---

<sup>* the actual types are more general</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You just want call `getLine` function `length_` times? It is as simple as

```
values <- (map read) <$> replicateM length_ getLine :: IO [Float]
```

Here `replicateM c a` performs `a` action `c` times. The `replicateM length_ getLine` expression returns an action that produces a list of strings, `IO [String]`. Using `<$>` operator (aka `fmap`) you can apply a function to `[String]` part of that `IO [String]` thing. Finally, the function we apply is `map read` converts a `String` into a `Float`, because we explicitly wrote the type of the whole expression.

It might be useful to you to see how `replicateM` itself is implemented:

```
replicateM cnt f =
    loop cnt
  where
    loop cnt = if cnt <= 0 then return [] else do
                    first <- f
                    leftover <- loop (cnt - 1)
                    return (f:leftover)
```

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong, but the implementation you provided crashes after I enter the number `2`

Comment: Crashes? Any error messages?

Comment: I had imported the wrong module